# iphonesdk contact listing indexing problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator, contacts, addressbook

i want to index my contact with alphabets but i am not getting the correct result, suppose if i click a, b or c in each section it showing all of the contacts ? how can i make sure that contact name starts with A will be indexed only in A section. and others in there respective sections, thanks in advance.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Normal table
    if (aTableView == tableView) 
        return self.contacts.count;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //  return self.contacts.count;
    return self.contacts.count;
}
```

Iam using Abcontact class.

also attached image for more clarification.

[image: repetition of same contacts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should implement

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

try use those tutorials

http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/

http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-development-creating-native.html

Comment: iam already using these thats why im getting A-Z alphabets in indexing.

Comment: - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 return[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];
}

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
 return index;
}

Comment: these are functions implementations which you are telling me :)

Comment: you need two arrays - 1. with first letters of words and 2. Array of words for those each letters. Plz read the tutorial!